# Cleanest way to repeat for of loop iteration under certain conditions in javascript?

Tags: javascript

This could be easily accomplished with a regular `for(;;)` loop, but I like using the `for (a of b)` loops and I'd like to know what would be cleanest way to repeat an iteration?

Something like:

```
for (const item of array){

    if (something){
        //repeat current iteration and don't go further down
    }    

    //do something

}
```

Comment: [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) ...?

Comment: @NinaScholz did u read carefully? Repeat the iteration, not skip to the next one.

Comment: @yegorchik This would create an infinite loop. Do you only want to repeat once?

Comment: @JayHales I want to repeat under certain conditions (like in example). Let's say I iterate through `[1, 2, 3]`. Each time I perform a request to the server. Once I get certain response, I want to repeat the iteration. So it could be like: 1, 2, 2, 3, etc. It could repeat once as well as 100 times if needed. Something like not allowing `i` to increment in the `for(;;)` loop. But in the `for of` one.

Comment: This would be an asynchronous loop so no stress in getting it repeat infinitely. I can track that and make it break if needed or continue to the next iteration. I want to be able to perform this in the `for of` loop with some clean syntax.

Comment: There's a balance between using modern syntax and using it to a degree that just makes your code more complex. These methods exist to simplify code so why overcomplicate your code just to include them?

Comment: @JayHales I'm not sure what you are trying to say. Maybe there's some clean way to achieve what I'm trying to. Why would I simply switch to default old school way without even searching for solution?

Comment: Because your code will become overcomplicated, more so than if you just use a good ol' `for(;;)`

Comment: @JayHales how can you claim that if you could just not be aware of some new feature or a good way someone found out? For example, the answer @NinaScholz provided with the use of the `while` loop could look better if I would accomplish in the `for(;;)` loop. It depends. But we have to constantly search and think!

Answer (score 4):

You could take a [`while` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while).

```
for (const item of array) {
    while (something) {
        //repeat current iteration and don't go further down
    }    
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Could be a solution, thanks. Would be glad to see more ways!

Comment: How do you realize _"and don't go further down"_ after the while loop is left?

Comment: @ThomasSablik, you could add another condition and continue the outer loop.

Comment: It seems the question is unclear and we interpret `//repeat current iteration and don't go further down` in a different way. For me it means after you enter the while loop don't `//do something`.

Comment: i don't see a problem here. js offers various statements for program flow.

Comment: @ThomasSablik it becomes unclear when you mix the `if` statement from the question and the `while` loop from this answer. So if we enter in the `while` loop we want to stay there until we reach the condition. Then we can go further down.

Comment: @ThomasSablik so this should work, as I can see. Read some comments from the question, I explained it a little bit more there.

Comment: @yegorchik it shouldn't be necessary to read comments to understand a question. Please update the question

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
restartTheLoop:
while (true) {
  for (const item of array){
     if (somethingHappend){
      continue restartTheLoop; //start all over again
     }
     //do stuff
   }

   break;
}
```

If somethingHappend is true, the continue restartTheLoop will go to the continue statement in the next iteration of the while loop. which then immediately starts the for loop from the beginning like you wish.
In case the the for iteration finishes (without somethingHappend evalute to true) the break statement will break out of the containing while loop.

Comment: Sure. Would appreciate a vote up

Answer (score 0):

How about using `do..while` with always false condition?

```
for (const item of [1, 2, 3, 4]) {
  do {
    const result = processItem(item);

    // will call processItem again for the same item if someCondition returns
    // truthy. Otherwise will start processing next item from the array
    if (someCondition(result)) continue;
  } while (0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind running again after the other items and changing the original array - you can push the item to the array.

```
let array=[1,2,3];
let repeated = {}

for (const item of array) {

    if (item % 2 === 0 && !repeated[item]) {
        console.log("not yet", item)
        repeated[item] = true;
        array.push(item)
        continue; // next iteration
    }

    console.log("doing", item);
}
```